# How to sync local folder with remote repo

Tags: git

I committed and pushed my local repo after I deleted a file, but I couldn't sync it with the remote repo, the file I deleted still remains the remote repo.

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Don't misuse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you deleted a file from the local repo, then commit the deletion:

```
git commit -a -m "A file was deleted"
```

And push your commit to remote:

```
git push
```

This should delete the file from remote repo too which you did from your local repo.